# Can Theano use the GPU on a Linux installed with Wubi?

Tags: gpu, theano, wubi

I have a computer running Microsoft Windows 7 with an Nvidia card. If I install Ubuntu with Wubi, can Theano use the GPU, and if so would it be just as efficiently as I was using Ubuntu without Wubi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wubi is just an easy way to install Ubuntu so it dual-boots with Windows. Once Ubuntu is installed neither Windows nor Ubuntu operate in any fundamentally different way compared to the same end result via an alternate installation method.

If you think that installing Ubuntu via Wubi will in some way change Windows so Theano on Windows can/must use the GPU differently/better then you're mistaken. You'll need to install Theano in each operating system you want to run it in. And the way in which Theano uses the GPU will be depend on each installation independent of any others. So, if you have a Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot system (whether that is achieved via Wubi or not), an installation of Theano in Windows will have no impact on an installation of Theano in Ubuntu, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly wondering whether using Wubi would make computation on GPU when using Theano slower.

Comment: Wubi is only a method of installation,  it doesn't change how Ubuntu runs after installation.